# Convert string to UTF8 Without BOM (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, encoding, byte-order-mark

I have issues writing a XML parser/merger, there is this XML that uses UTF8-BOM encoding and I get an error while using XElement.Parse. However if I convert that file to UTF8 without BOM it solves the issue.

The error is "-     {"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."}".

This XML is downloaded from a SOAP API to a Byte stream and then converted to a string like this:

```
Dim sourceFile_as_Byte = SOAPAPI.Download 'I download the file using a SOAP API method.
Dim ByteEncoder As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
SourceFile_as_string = ByteEncoder.GetString(SourceFile_as_Byte)
Dim XMLdoc As XElement
XMLdoc = XElement.Parse(SourceFile_as_string)
```

I've found other solutions like using XElement.Load which works regardless (seems .Load manages the encoding?) but due to the nature of the solution I need to use the Parse method so that's why I'm trying to convert that string and remove the BOM.

Thanks

Comment: You could use the [UTF8Encoding.GetString(Byte(), Int32, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding.getstring): `Dim sourceFileAsString = byteEncoder.GetString(sourceFileAsByte, 3, sourceFileAsByte.Length - 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

[Encoding.UTF8.GetString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring) / [GetChars()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getchars) are known to also include the BOM in the string it creates from the byte array passed to the methods (you can see that the string is 1 char longer when the source file is saved with the BOM).
You can remove the char, in case it's there, using the [TrimStart()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart) method.
The Unicode char is `\uFEFF` or `ChrW(&HFEFF)`.

```
Dim sourceBytes = SOAPAPI.Download
Dim xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sourceBytes).TrimStart(ChrW(&HFEFF))
Dim xmlDoc = XElement.Parse(xml)
```